# What is the most popular backend framework is used for ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, express, backend

My existing project I have :

Frontend Framework - **PHP Codeigniter** and **PHP Laravel**

Backend Framework - **JAVA Springboot**

I'm trying to change Frontend Framework to **ReactJS**. I want to know what is the most popular backend framework to use with ReactJS and Why? Please explain. Should I change Backend Framework from Springboot to other one such as **ExpressJS**?. How about the performance?.

Thank in advanced.

Comment: Simply in the "common sense" backend only serves data from _some database_ to **React front**, though there is no limitation in use as almost any backend technology serves REST without a problem. The major factor would be lying on business logic, Java gives your code more confidence (security), Python fit better for algorithmic tasks which has great support in it, PHP is still widely used and NodeJS allows you to do magic on backend, eg. Server Side Rendering your SPA app. This is just the minimal as possible comparison, please do not hate :)

Comment: I concern about large number of connection and concurrency because my project has > 140k session of user

Comment: Best possible performance nowadays you would probably achieve with Go, the viable choice would be still NodeJS as it has great concurrency performance with it's asynchronous design (but it has drawbacks, single-threaded etc.), Python can also support concurrency but is generally known as being a bit less performant, PHP does not support threading at all so I would not recommend for your case. Java with Spring Reactive model can also be nice choice for you, as it works non-blocking giving you better performance than standard synchronous way.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer NodeJS + ExpressJS because this framework are js based and widely support by community.

Comment: NodeJs and ExpressJs are better choice

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer you from personal Experience.

**1. NodeJS + ExpressJS**
This combination is the most basic version of a backend for React but very effective. For most of you application this should be enough. You can achieve everything you want with this. The performance is great.

**2. Strapi** ***Highly Recommended***
Strapi ([Official Page](https://strapi.io/)) is a great framework as backend. Most of the typical functions you want for a backend are already implemented or can be easily added. Performance is also great.

**3. Meteor** ***Recommended***
Meteor ([Official Page](https://www.meteor.com/)) is an all around package. Many Plugins and a active community. Excellent for beginner and great for experienced user. Easy to setup and it also manage you database for you if you want. Performance is ok